# Involving probability, distinct integers and linear search algorithms...

Tags: probability

So here is me, working hard for extra points in highschool, when I stumble across a question that threw me off... During a test no less... So I asked the teacher if I could note it down, and am now posting my question here to the geniuses to help me not only find the answer, but also understand how it works. This is my first time posting a question, so I hope this bears fruit!

Here's how the question was posed.

"Suppose that the probability that a number, x, is in a list of n distinct integers is 3/4 and that it is just as likely that x equals any element in the list."

"**Find the average number of comparisons used by the *linear search algorithm* to find x OR to determine that it is not in the list.**"

I'm hoping I can get some sort of explanation so that I can present the answer to the class. No longer for extra grades, but I'm curious.

Comment: Care to tell us what a linear search algorithm is for completeness sake?

Comment: It's a way of finding an element in the list, by systematically going through each other element until the one you wanted is found.

At least, that's the most I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may require knowledge above that taught in high school, but I will try to keep it as simple as possible. The first thing to realize is that the probability must be proportional to the length of the list we need to search. Firstly, for simplicity let us say one comparison is comparing one number to the desired $x$ we want to find. We know that the probability that $x$ is in the list is $\frac{3}{4}$. Denote the length of the list as $L$. 
Firstly, suppose that $x$ is in the list. What is the probability that some random element in the list we choose is $x$? Well if the probability is all equiprobable (uniform distribution) across the entire list then clearly is it just $\frac{1}{L}$.

Suppose two possibilites. $x$ is in the list and $x$ is not in the list.

#### x is in the list

Then the probability that any $x$ we are searching for is the $x$ we want is $\frac{1}{L}$, then the expected number of comparisons is half the size of the list $\frac{L}{2}$ (i.e. we will on average need to preform $\frac{L}{2}$ comparisons to find $x$ if it is in the list).

#### x is not in the list

Then we will need to do all $L$ comparison to confirm this. 
Thus we know that $x$ is in the list with probabiltiy $\frac{3}{4}$, thus it must NOT be in the list with probability $\frac{1}{4}$, thus weighing these probability we have:
$$\frac{3}{4}\frac{L}{2} + \frac{1}{4}L$$
Is the expected number of comparisons

Comment: The one question I have to this amazing explanation (if you don't mind me copying that down for later reference) is: Where does the linear search algorithm come in? Or am I just missing the whole meaning of that...

Comment: @Chimiboy, we wish to compute the expected cost of the linear search algorithm and there are only 2 possibilites, $x$ is in the list or $x$ is not in the list. If $x$ is in the list, the average number of comparison we will need to do to find $x$ is just half of the list length (why?). If $x$ is not in the list, we need to traverse the entirety of the list to confirm it is not. We now have the expected costs of both of the outcomes, so we weigh them according to their probability of occuring to find the total expected cost.

Comment: @Chimiboy, feel free to ask any questions if you have any, I'd be more then happy to explain if I wasn't clear on anything

Comment: It does make sense, and I'm very glad it does now! Thank you for your help! I just looked up how the Linear search algorithm works, and that basically blew away all question I had about this answer.

Comment: Thanks! If an answer helped you or you think it is satsifactory, please remember to accept it to that other future users can see it. Enjoy your time at SO